# Selenium IDE - Showing an unexpected Alert! When generating the random email ID

Tags: javascript, file, selenium, ide

I am using below code in selenium IDE for generate random email. Its working fine and email was generated but showing an error in IDE i.e. "[error] Error: There was an unexpected Alert! [Invalid Email Address]"

```
Selenium.prototype.doGenerateUserRandomEmail= function(locator)
{
var randomString= '';
randomnum=randomnum+Math.floor(Math.random() * 999);
randomString += "khushboo" + "+" + randomnum + "@ranosys.com";
selenium.doType(locator, randomString);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is coming from your application, **not** Selenium-IDE. You have to make sure the email address that you are generating is valid, as per your application.